# Android - interstitial ads - Stopping my all sounds on full load

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

i just discovered that on interstitial load at the background stopping my all sounds.

i got following in each activity resulting stopping any kinds of interstitial load at the background

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

please help with it

thanks

Comment: What's the issue you need help with?

Comment: or in another words my sound stops randomly

Comment: how to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

According to Google's best practices for interstitial ads:-
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial

> Remember to pause the action when displaying an interstitial. There
>   are a number of different types of interstitial ads: text, image,
>   video, and more. It's important to make sure that when your
>   application displays an interstitial, it also suspends its use of some
>   resources in order to allow the ad to take advantage of them. For
>   example, when you make the call to display an interstitial, **be sure to
>   pause any audio output being produced by your app. You can resume
>   playing sounds in the onAdClosed event handler**, which will be invoked
>   when the user has finished interacting with the ad. In addition,
>   consider temporarily halting any intense computation tasks (such as a
>   game loop) while the ad is being displayed. **This will make sure the
>   user doesn't experience janky graphics or stuttered video.**

Summary: Sound is paused so that user can view ad without any issue. While you can definitely play the sound in background , I would advice not to do that as it would interfere with ads.